# What is a proxy class in a Web Service world?

Tags: java, web-services, soap, proxy, wsdl

I am reading ***Professional XML
By: Bill Evjen; Kent Sharkey; Thiru Thangarathinam; Michael Kay; Alessandro Vernet; Sam Ferguson***

Chapter ***SOAP*** & ***WSDl*** focusses on,
After you have found the service you want to consume, the act of discovery should bring you to the location of the Web service's WSDL file. The WSDL file is an XML description of the Web service's interface. After you have found the ***WSDL*** file of the Web service, you can create a ***proxy class (or your environment automatically creates one for you)*** that enables you to send messages back and forth to the Web service.

What is the proxy class in para above means and by whom it gets instantiated?
Is the Web Method which I wish to invoke through the SOAP constructed message format is also a method of the object of the proxy class?

Answer (score 1):

The WSDL file is the technical contract which defines the communication interface with a service.

The "proxy class" in your citation, is just the logical representation of the service in your program. You can do this class by yourself, or have it made automatically. Most IDEs out there allow you to import a WSDL and they will generate most of the code needed to communicate with the service. The import tool will most likely create classes with methods and variables that correspond directly to operations and types in the WSDL file.

Your application instantiates the class and you call the methods you need to call by just filling the data as parameters and receiving the response in return. The class handles Object to SOAP message conversion for you. Keep in mind that even though it looks very similar to local function call, it is not - it is not nearly as fast and it involves network communication risks. It is quite possible to have communication errors that you need to handle.